# Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, dalvik, dex

I can't run my project. I've download the project from here. When i'm going to run this project. It raises this error : -

```
[2011-11-02 06:22:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-11-02 06:22:04 - jberkel-sms-backup-plus-9a8489a] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
```

I just referred some links from google for this error. They told that clean the project using project > clean Am also tried this method. But, the same error will raise from here after. What can i do for this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you try eclipse close and then start again? its for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also having this same problem once a time. Just Restart your Eclipse and run the project again. It'll clear. Hope this will help you.